# Bot build failed on herokou after i added SQlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, heroku, discord, discord.py

my bot was working file untill i imported SQlite3 and now it isnt building, here is the error

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack

-----> Python app detected

-----> Requirements file has been changed, clearing cached dependencies

-----> Installing python-3.6.12

-----> Installing pip 20.1.1, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.34.2

-----> Installing SQLite3

-----> Installing requirements with pip

       Collecting discord

         Downloading discord-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 kB)

       Collecting TenGiphPy

         Downloading TenGiphPy-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (3.3 kB)

       ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement SQLite3 (from -r /tmp/build_2560183b_/requirements.txt (line 3)) (from versions: none)

       ERROR: No matching distribution found for SQLite3 (from -r /tmp/build_2560183b_/requirements.txt (line 3))

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.

 !     Push failed
```

any ideas?
i've tried tried alot of stuff like changing the capitalization on SQLite in the requirements.txt

Comment: show me your requirements.text file

Comment: @NikhilSingh 
here:
```
discord
TenGiphPy
SQLite3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to install sqlite3 module. It is included in the standard library (since Python 2.5).

if it still doesnt work instead of adding
`SQLite3` use `pysqlite3`
in requirements.txt